# Removing sensitive info from all Git commits

Tags: git, github

Say I have sensitive info, such as a corporate IP address in a Git commit, in fact perhaps 100s of commits. Is there a way to remove/replace that token from all commits using a Git command?

Comment: Is an IP address really that sensitive? You'll have to rewrite a lot of commit history.

Comment: well lets say it is, how can I delete old commits or rewrite them?

Answer (score 3):

[Github suggests](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/) the easiest way is using a program called [BFG repo cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/).

> ### Using the BFG
>
> The BFG Repo-Cleaner is a faster, simpler alternative to `git filter-branch`
>   for removing unwanted data. For example, to remove your
>   file with sensitive data and leave your latest commit untouched), run:
>
> ```
> bfg --delete-files YOUR-FILE-WITH-SENSITIVE-DATA
> ```
>
> To replace all text listed in passwords.txt wherever it can be found
>   in your repository's history, run:
>
> ```
> bfg --replace-text passwords.txt
> ```
>
> See the BFG Repo-Cleaner's documentation for full usage and download
>   instructions.

If you're pushing this repo to a centralised location, **ensure all the developers know what you are doing beforehand**. Otherwise, you'll get some very upset people with very broken repositories and lost commits. You will also need to force a push to remote because you are rewriting history. This process is generally a huge hassle for everyone which is why I asked whether an IP address is sensitive enough to warrant this response.

On the security side, if these commits have already been made public, you should immediately assume that the **confidentiality of information in the commits are compromised**. You should immediately take appropriate security measures to mitigate any risks at this point.