# remove all but selected files in all Git commits

Tags: git, bash, pattern-matching, glob, git-filter-branch

I have several "interesting" files (which I have touched) among all other files in the Git history. And I want to publish the "interesting" files only with their history as a Git repo, without any other files being present anywhere in the history of this repo.

How to write a smart script for `git filter-branch --index-filter`? (Or at least for `git filter-branch --tree-filter`, which is however undesirable, since it is slower, and my saved trees are huge.)

Note that my question is a bit different to the most common similar one people are asking [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38650355/94687)[2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36734436/94687): *How to remove a specific ("sensitive") file from the Git history?* I need to remove the complement, and keep the specific files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the tricky part in this script for `git filter-branch --index-filter` is to get the list of files from the index, filter out the specific ones, and then remove the resulting list.

I have implemented this as a separate executable script [`git-update-index-keeping-only`](http://git.altlinux.org/gears/g/git-update-index-keeping-only.git?p=git-update-index-keeping-only.git;a=blob;f=git-update-index-keeping-only;h=601dd4dfdc0d97cceebf2d5cada366babdb44523;hb=HEAD); here is the rough implementation:

```
git ls-files --full-name \
| fgrep -v -x -f <(echo "$FILELIST") \
| xargs git rm --cached "$@" --
```

where I haven't thought much about what would happen to newlines and spaces in the filenames (spaces must be a problem for `xargs`, unless it is told to invoke the command again for each argument, which I didn't do for efficiency).

A sample usage is written down in another script useful for my use case: get the list of interesting as those modified or added in the diff between 2 commits (say, an "upstream" commit and your last commit on top of that).

It's [git-filter-only-files-modified-since](http://git.altlinux.org/gears/g/git-update-index-keeping-only.git?p=git-update-index-keeping-only.git;a=blob;f=git-filter-only-files-modified-since;h=5282a6f85acad633169ca6b7d96f015ecd24edc9;hb=HEAD); its essence is like this:

```
FILES="$(git diff-tree "$SINCE": HEAD: \
   -r --name-only --diff-filter=MACRT)"
export FILES
git filter-branch \
   --index-filter 'echo "$FILES" | git-update-index-keeping-only -q'
```